# Optimizing UDP connection

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am working on a program with which you can control a cursor from another system. For that I use a udp socket. With the code I currently use, I get a pretty laggy result.

This is my current code:

---

```py
# client
import socket
import sys
import pyautogui
import time

IP_ADDRESS = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 65432


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as client:
        prev_x, prev_y = 0, 0
        while True:
            x, y = pyautogui.position()
            if prev_x == x and prev_y == y:
                continue

            client.sendto(f'{x} {y}'.encode(), (IP_ADDRESS, PORT))
            prev_x, prev_y = x, y
            time.sleep(0.0005)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```py
# server
import socket
import sys
import pyautogui
import time


IP_ADDRESS = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 65432


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as server:
        server.bind((IP_ADDRESS, PORT))
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1)

        while True:
            data, sender = server.recvfrom(1024)
            x, y = [int(i) for i in data.split()]
            pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
            time.sleep(0.0005)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Any suggestions on how to make this less laggy?

Comment: Don't sleep after `recvfrom`.  It will block anyway until data are received and adding a sleep will just slow it down. Apart from that `SO_REUSEPORT` must be done before the `bind`, not after.

Comment: Removing the sleep barely makes a difference

Comment: What exactly do you mean with laggy? How much delay you experience (maybe add some timestamp to the message to find out, but make sure that the clocks are actually in sync)? What is time you measure with ping between client and server system?

Comment: there is a very minor delay which is not a problem. But the mouse movement is very jittery. May this be because of the packages not being received in the correct order?

Comment: *"May this be because of the packages not being received in the correct order?"* - unlikely. But just print out what you send and what you receive and then compare. Then you can also observe what the actual values for the positions are - maybe it looks jittery because you are not scanning fast enough to get a smooth update.

Comment: It seems quit a few packages get lost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254355/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-vsteppy).

Comment: Your sending program shouldn't send UDP packets every 0.0005 seconds; rather it should send a UDP packet whenever the cursor's position changes.  (Well, maybe also send a packet once or twice a second even if the cursor hasn't moved, just to recover in case a packet got dropped).  Flooding the network with redundant position data will degrade performance as buffers fill up and packets start to get dropped.

Comment: There should be a sleep before the `continue`., Otherwise you're smoking the CPU while the position doesn't change. The other sleeps are both pointless as stated above. UDP can indeed both lose and re-order datagrams, and also deliver them more than once. There is nothing you can do about that. And don't set SO_RCVBUF to 1. It won't be honoured, as the system will impose its own minimum, and you're trying to receive up to 1024 bytes, so what exactly is the point? And there is no such thing as a 'UDP connection'.